# gradle publish.dependsOn('assemble') not working

Tags: android, gradle

I've added this line in my gradle file:

```
project.tasks.findByName('publish').dependsOn('assemble')
```

But an error occurred when executing `publish` task:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apn:publishLibraryPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'library' to repository 'maven'
   > Invalid publication 'library': artifact file does not exist: '/Users/yuanhaodong/Projects/Bk/code_base/blackkey_android/modules/apn/build/outputs/aar/apn-release.aar'
```

I've tried `project.tasks.findByName('publish').dependsOn('assembleRelease')` but still no luck.

Then I changed to

```
project.tasks.findByName('publishLibraryPublicationToMavenRepository').dependsOn('assemble')
```

but `project.tasks.findByName('publishLibraryPublicationToMavenRepository')` returns null instead.

Gradle version: 4.10.1
Android gradle plugin version: 3.3.0

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have your `publish*` task (from the `maven-publish` plugin) to depend on the corresponding `assemble*` task, add this to the root of your app's `build.gradle`:

```
/* Restricting publications to specific repositories */
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) { task ->
    onlyIf {[...]}

    def match = task.name =~ '^publish(.*)(Release|Debug)PublicationTo(.*)$'
    dependsOn("assemble${match[0][1]}")
}
```

The assemble task's name is computed from the publish task's name, which is constructed as [publish**PubName**PublicationTo**RepoName**Repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-publish` plugin adds its tasks lazily based on the configured publications, so they are not yet available when `project.tasks.findByName` is executed on another project.

You can achieve the correct result if you wrap your code in an afterEvaluate block:

```
// Kotlin Syntax
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository::class.java) {
        dependsOn(tasks.assemble)
    }
}
```